# Related Rates - two airplanes, both rates given. Find rate of distance

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question reads "Two aircraft are in the same airspace with Plane A 500km south of Plane B. If Plane A is traveling 600 km/h due south while Plane B is travelling 800km/h due west, determine how quickly the distance between the planes is changing."

My solution:

$\frac{dA}{dt} = 600km/h$

$\frac{dB}{dt} = 800 km/h$

$A = 500km$

$B = 0km$

$d = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$

$\frac{dd}{dt} = \frac{A\frac{dA}{dt} + B\frac{dB}{dt}}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$

Plugging in the values from above:
$\frac{dd}{dt} = \frac{0 + 500(600)}{\sqrt{500^2}}$

$\frac{dd}{dt} = 600 km/h $

Did I do this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your procedure is correct.

And yes your answer is correct because
$$ 600^2+0^2=600^2$$
From Planes A point of view at that instant Plane B is not moving. While From Planes B point of view at that instant  Plane A is moving away from it at 600 km/h.